# Find /dev entry with VID/PID of USB device

Tags: linux, usb, usb-drive

I'd like to make a program that will detect which `/dev/sd*` entry is linked to a known USB VID/PID pair.

Do you know how I can get the VID/PID of a USB stick that would appear as `/dev/sd*`?

Comment: I'd look into libudev.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use `udevadm` for this

in the output of `udevadm info -q property -n /dev/sd*` the VID is in the `ID_VENDOR_ID` field and the PID is in the `ID_MODEL_ID` field

you can extract this using `grep / sed`...