# Mapping Serial number or pid|vid of connected usb drive to its mountpoint

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi

Need help for mapping Serial number or pid|vid of connected usb drive to its mountpoint. I got the parameters of the connected flash drive using c library 'libusb'. They look like this:

```
Product: USB Flash Disk
Serial Number: XXXXXXXXXXXXX
PID:VID: XXXX:XXXX
```

I need to map them to a mountpoint (e.g. in raspberry-pi */media/pi/<flash_drive_name>*)

Comment: Have a look here... https://stackoverflow.com/a/47418515/2836621

Comment: And here... https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/66916/400632